# Computer Invisible On Domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, domain-controller

One of our Linux users attempted to install Cygwin on our Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller.  Now it is no longer possible to browse the domain and see all of the computers.  For example, \\my_domain_name will just bring up a username/password dialog box (that will not accept any username or password, even the domain administrator) and no computers will ever be listed.

However, I can still connect to computers based on their name or IP address.  So \\eridanus or \\192.168.1.85 still work to connect to the shared directories of computers on our network.

Does anyone know where I can find these settings?  and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: It may be worth noting that the computers are still visible under the "Computers" section of the Active Directory.

The cygwin installation failed due to issues with group policies, or something of the like.  The Linux user isn't really sure what happens, and curses Windows everytime I try to ask him what he's done.

We have no network admin since we're a very small company, so it's up to the programmer (me!) to figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to add comments to my question - So I'll add more information here in an answer if that's ok.

I've just finished uninstalling Cygwin - they don't have an uninstaller, so it's completely manual.  It looks like he also installed Singular, another Linux app...  I'll see if I can remove it as well.

There's still no change on accessing the domain via \\my_domain_name.

Comment: Is there a way to perform a limited system restore on domain settings?